# Count results generated by case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a query that analyzes two records and checks whether one record matches the second record. If record 1 column matches record 2 column then there's no error. If record 1 column does not match record 2 column then there's an error. I want to be able to count the errors per YPID. For the life of me... I can't figure it out. Help!

Here's my query:

```
select r1.ypid, r1.business_name as Base_Listed_Name, r1.street_address as Base_Listed_Address, r1.city as Base_Listed_City, r1.state as Base_Listed_State, r1.zip5 as Base_Listed_Zip, rmve1.value as Base_URL,
r2.business_name as Google_Scanned_Listed_Name, r2.street_address as Google_Scanned_Listed_Address, r2.city as Google_Scanned_Listed_City, r2.state as Google_Scanned_Listed_City, r2.zip5 as Google_Scanned_Listed_Zip, rmve2.value as Google_Scanned_URL,
ls.presence_score, ls.listing_score,
case
when r1.business_name = r2.business_name then 'no_error'
else 'error'
end Business_Name_Status,
case
when r1.latitude = r2.latitude then  'no_error'
when r1.longitude = r2.longitude then  'no_error'
when r1.latitude is null or r1.latitude in ('0') then (case when r1.street_address = r2.street_address then 'no_error' else 'error' end)
else 'error'
end Street_Address_Status,
case
when r1.city = r2.city then 'no_error'
else 'error'
end City_Status,
case
when r1.state = r2.state then 'no_error'
else 'error'
end State_Status,
case
when r1.zip5 = r2.zip5 then 'no_error'
else 'error'
end Zip_Status,
case
when lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(rmve1.value, 'http://www.', null), 'www.', null), 'https://www.', null), 'http://', null), 'https://', null), 'wwww.', null)) 
= lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(rmve2.value, 'http://www.', null), 'www.', null), 'https://www.', null), 'http://', null), 'https://', null), 'wwww.', null)) then 'no_error'
else 'error'
end URL_Status
from mdm2.records r1 join mdm2.records r2 on r1.ypid = r2.ypid join mdm2.presence_listing_statuses ls on r1.ypid = ls.ypid 
left outer join mdm2.record_mult_val_exts rmve1 on r1.id = rmve1.record_id and rmve1.extension_type = 'urls' and rmve1.value_type = 'primary'
left outer join mdm2.record_mult_val_exts rmve2 on r2.id = rmve2.record_id and rmve2.extension_type = 'urls' and rmve2.value_type = 'primary'
where r1.ypid in ('5625222','13846403','21974776','22806234','30303664','453728041')
and r1.source_code = 'PPA'
and r2.source_code = 'GOOG';  

results
|YPID|BASE_LISTED_NAME|BASE_LISTED_ADDRESS|BASE_LISTED_CITY|BASE_LISTED_STATE|BASE_LISTED_ZIP|BASE_URL|GOOGLE_SCANNED_LISTED_NAME|GOOGLE_SCANNED_LISTED_ADDRESS|GOOGLE_SCANNED_LISTED_CITY|GOOGLE_SCANNED_LISTED_CITY_1|GOOGLE_SCANNED_LISTED_ZIP|GOOGLE_SCANNED_URL|PRESENCE_SCORE|LISTING_SCORE|BUSINESS_NAME_STATUS|STREET_ADDRESS_STATUS|CITY_STATUS|STATE_STATUS|ZIP_STATUS|URL_STATUS|
|5625222|Affinity Insurance Agency|5702 S Staples St Suite G|Corpus Christi|TX|78413|http://affinityia.com|Affinity Insurance Agency|5702 S Staples St Suite G|Corpus Christi|TX|78413|http://corpuschristiinsuranceprovider.com|90|97|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|error|
|13846403|Party Bazaar|4435 Lovers Ln|Dallas|TX|75225|www.partybazaardallas.com|Party Bazaar|4435 Lovers Ln|Dallas|TX|75225|http://partybazaardallas.com|93|100|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|
|21974776|Alterations To Go|2100 Arden Way Ste 150|Sacramento|CA|95825|http://www.alterationstogosacramento.com|Alterations To Go|2100 Arden Way # 150|Sacramento|CA|95825|http://alterations-togo.com|91|99|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|error|
|22806234|RV America|3640 Chambers Rd|Aurora|CO|80011|http://www.rvamericainc.com/pages/rv%20financing|RV America|3640 Chambers Rd|Aurora|CO|80011|http://rvamericainc.com|83|91|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|error|
|30303664|Sorelli Hair Studio & Spa|400 Saint Andrews Blvd|Melbourne|FL|32940|http://sorellihairstudio.com|Sorelli Hair Studio & Spa|400 Saint Andrews Blvd|Melbourne|FL|32940|http://sorellihairstudio.com|91|99|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|
|453728041|Carolina Driving School|534 Walkertown Guthrie Rd|Winston Salem|NC|27101|http://www.carolinadriving.com|Carolina Driving School|534 Walkertown Guthrie Rd|Winston Salem|NC|27101|http://carolinadrivingschool.com|87|97|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|no_error|error|
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to count the number of times "error" appears for a given row? A synthetic/simple example would make things clearer.

Comment: My apologies, misinterpretted the other question.

Comment: This is a tough one. I'd recommend either using a pivot table or a cursor. Either way it will be slow.

Comment: @Mat - Yes, that's what I am looking for. I need to count the number of times 'error' appears for a given row.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to use LEAD , LAG function .

check this link http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php

LAG function is used to access data from a previous row
LEAD function is used to return data from the next row.

by this you can compare 1st row with 2nd row

Comment: You helped me solve a different problem I had. Although not this specific one... I thank you for the info.